# How to access all the data saved in a h5py file

Tags: python

I save a number of numpy arrays into a h5py file with different names corresponding to different datasets. Assuming I don't know those dataset names, how to access the saved data after reading the h5py file. For example:

```
f = h5py.file('filename','w')
f.create_dataset('file1',data=data1)
.... 

F = h5py.file('filename','r')
#next how to read out all the datasets without knowing their names in a prior
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filenames = list(F.keys()) #which contains all the dataset names
data1 = F[filenames[0]].value.astype('float32') 
...
```

See also the post [How to know HDF5 dataset name in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45280185/how-to-know-hdf5-dataset-name-in-python)